# Android Studio Gradle issue after updating to version 0.6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Since I updated Android Studio to version 0.6.0 I'm facing following issue with Gradle Sync:

[image]

There's a discussion on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tzof6zatrJW) and [Google adt-dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/A9e-78LVz8E) which suggests that the auto enabling of new Manifest Merger causing the issue. The discussion and solution is so unclear on both platforms, although I did try to add `android { useOldManifestMerger true; }` as suggested in build.gradle but I'm still getting this error.

P.S: We're using RoboGuice and suspecting that it could be compatibility issue.

Here's the log:

```
2014-06-09 11:07:35,927 [ 171888]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:352)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:334)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:364)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:330)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)

2014-06-09 11:07:35,927 [ 171888]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter -  
2014-06-09 11:07:35,927 [ 171888]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectImporter - Cause: com.android.builder.BuilderConstants
```

Comment: I reverted back to 0.5.9 until this is solved. you can download it here. http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-5-9
0.6.0 it's just a few bug fixes, 0.5.9 was the major one IMO.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your build files? The package location of the BuilderConstants has changed; see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/A9e-78LVz8E/erI8q5ZM8qYJ

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I had to comment:

```
apply plugin: 'android-test'
```

and

```
testCompile 'junit: junit: 4.10'
testCompile 'org.robolectric: robolectric: 2.3'
testCompile 'com.squareup: fest-android: 1.0 +.'

instrumentTestCompile 'junit: junit: 4.10'
instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric: robolectric: 2.3'
instrumentTestCompile 'com.squareup: fest-android: 1.0 +.'
```

My problem was the plugin support for test:
https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle/issues/11

I recommend you follow this post:
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Tzof6zatrJW

And this:
https://github.com/robolectric/gradle-android-test-plugin/pull/33

Answer (score 0):

Try this [post](http://raptordigital.blogspot.be/2014/06/robolectric-plugin-upgraded-to-011x.html). The robolectric plugin has been updated to a new version.